# Is it possible to hook up a more robust HTML parser to Python mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to parse and submit a form on a website using mechanize, but it appears that the built-in form parser cannot detect the form and its elements. I suspect that it is choking on poorly formed HTML, and I'd like to try pre-parsing it with a parser better designed to handle bad HTML (say lxml or BeautifulSoup) and then feeding the prettified, cleaned-up output to the form parser. I need mechanize not only for submitting the form but also for maintaining sessions (I'm working this form from within a login session.)

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, if it is indeed possible.. I'm not that familiar with the various details of the HTTP protocol, how to get various parts to work together etc. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reading from the big example on the first page of the [mechanize website](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
# Sometimes it's useful to process bad headers or bad HTML:
response = br.response()  # this is a copy of response
headers = response.info()  # currently, this is a mimetools.Message
headers["Content-type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
response.set_data(response.get_data().replace("<!---", "<!--"))
br.set_response(response)
```

so it seems very possible to preprocess the response with another parser which will regenerate well-formed HTML, then feed it back to mechanize for further processing.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I missed that. Then again, the mechanize docs aren't exactly the best organized ones around. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had a problem where a form field was missing from a form, I couldn't find any malformed html but I figured that was the cause so I used BeautifulSoup's prettify function to parse it and it worked.

```
resp = br.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.get_data())
resp.set_data(soup.prettify())
br.set_response(resp)
```

I'd love to know how to this automatically.

Edit: found out how to do this automatically

```
class PrettifyHandler(mechanize.BaseHandler):
    def http_response(self, request, response):
        if not hasattr(response, "seek"):
            response = mechanize.response_seek_wrapper(response)
        # only use BeautifulSoup if response is html
        if response.info().dict.has_key('content-type') and ('html' in response.info().dict['content-type']):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.get_data())
            response.set_data(soup.prettify())
        return response

    # also parse https in the same way
    https_response = http_response

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.add_handler(PrettifyHandler())
```

`br` will now use `BeautifulSoup` to parse all responses where html is contained in the content type (mime type), eg `text/html`

Comment: Have you tested the updated solution (`PrettifyHandler`)? Didn't work for me.

Comment: @sirfz I tested it at the time and it worked. I haven't used mechanize or BeautifulSoup for several years, maybe it doesn't work with the current versions. Are you sure that your response has a `content-type` header that includes the string `html`?

Comment: yes I added a pdb inside `http_response` before the condition and it never reached it. I guess it's as you said, not compatible with the latest version although it would've been very convenient.

Comment: Make sure you've also got an https_response method (e.g. https_response = http_response) otherwise all HTTPS traffic will skip the http method - I lost hours to this and assumed I was having the same issue as @sirfz

Comment: @jmc that's a good catch. I think I didn't spend much time with it and just went with the accepted answer instead but this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @sirfz No worries, thanks for editing it, my identical edit got rejected by the Stackoverflows appalling editing review process - interestingly you got 1 reject on your edit too. It's funny just how bad the reviewing of edits is and there's simply no way to appeal a review. So many good edits of mine get lost to this nonsense, I wonder how much good content and corrections to answers disappears into the ether due to this.

Comment: Very weird @jmc, I guess I was luckier with the reviewers. Bummer that such helpful edits get rejected sometimes. Anyway, thanks for your input here, makes things much nicer!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be done with `lxml.etree` which is the `xml.etree.ElementTree` emulator (and replacement) provided by `lxml`:

First we take bad mal-formed HTML:

```
% cat bad.html
<html>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>this HTML is awful</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>THIS IS H1</H1>
    <A HREF=MYLINK.HTML>This is a link and it is awful</a>
    <img src=yay.gif>
</body>
</html>
```

(Observe the mixed case between opening and closing tags, missing quotation marks).

And then parse it:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> bad = file('bad.html').read()
>>> html = etree.HTML(bad)
>>> print etree.tostring(html)
<html><head><title>this HTML is awful</title></head><body>
    <h1>THIS IS H1</h1>
    <a href="MYLINK.HTML">This is a link and it is awful</a>
    <img src="yay.gif"/></body></html>
```

Observe that the tagging and quotation has been corrected for us.

If you were having problems parsing the HTML before, this might be the answer you're looking for.  As for the details of HTTP, that is another matter entirely.

Comment: I do know how to use lxml, actually.. :P I was just wondering how to get it to work with mechanize.