# Python's Mechanize not recognizing a form that the HTML and BeautifulSoup does

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm submitting a form, which then has a confirmation page.  At the confirmation page in a browser there is an  that is an image the user clicks to confirm the order.

Mechanize is not recognizing the form at all when it is present in the HTML mech has:

```
content = mech.submit().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup.findAll('form')
```

displays the correct form, while mech claims there are no forms present.  I have tried doing:

```
mech.click(inputName)
```

and mech claims the input does not exist.  Meanwhile the input shows up just fine with:

```
print soup.findAll('input')
```

Any ideas?  I have also done this:

```
mech = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
```

With no luck.

Comment: You're seriously expecting a response without giving the data? Share what the HTML *is* and you're more likely to get a response. It's likely to be some parsing issue which may be able to be remedied.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing all html responses with BeautifulSoup, then mechanize should recognise the form. 
You can see how to do it in this answer [Is it possible to hook up a more robust HTML parser to Python mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782368/is-it-possible-to-hook-up-a-more-robust-html-parser-to-python-mechanize/5039584#5039584)