# Submitting nested form with python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, python-2.7

I am trying to submit a login form on a web page that looks something like this. I have also tried submit the nested form as well as submit both forms, same error every time.

```
<form method="post" name="loginform">
     <input type='hidden' name='login' value='1'>
     <form action="#" method="post" id="login">
          Username
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
          Password
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
          <input type="submit" value='Login'  class="submit" />
```

here is my the python script I am using. I also noted that the forms aren't closed off with `</form>` I am not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()

br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

br.open('http://www.example.com/')

br.select_form(name="loginform")

br['login'] = '1'
br['username'] = 'user'
br['password'] = 'pass'

resp = br.submit()
```

the error I get is

```
ParseError: nested FORMs
```

**Edit:**

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import MinimalSoup 

class PrettifyHandler(mechanize.BaseHandler):
    def http_response(self, request, response):
        if not hasattr(response, "seek"):
            response = mechanize.response_seek_wrapper(response)
        # only use BeautifulSoup if response is html
        if response.info().dict.has_key('content-type') and ('html' in response.info().dict['content-type']):
            soup = MinimalSoup (response.get_data())
            response.set_data(soup.prettify())
        return response

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.add_handler(PrettifyHandler())

br.open('http://example.com/')

br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['username'] = 'mrsmith'
br.form['password'] = '123abc'
resp = br.submit()

print resp.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [ICantBelieveItsBeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Other%20Built-In%20Parsers) or MinimalSoup parser instead of BeautifulSoup, see [Is it possible to hook up a more robust HTML parser to Python mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782368/is-it-possible-to-hook-up-a-more-robust-html-parser-to-python-mechanize/5039584#5039584) for implementation

Comment: Tried and ICBIBS gave me the same error, MinimalSoup didn't give any errors, it just didn't work. I edited to show the code I used. +1 for good info though maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking for the offending section of the page and adjusting it manually. For example I had a page that was getting the nested forms issue and I found that there was

```
<FORM></FORM>
```

sitting inside another form block. I also needed to remove the first line because that was also formatted badly. So you could try something like this:

```
...
resp = br.open(url)  # Load login page
# the [111:0] takes away the first 111 chars of the response
# the .replace('<FORM></FORM>','') removes the bad HTML
resp.set_data(resp.get_data()[111:].replace('<FORM></FORM>',''))  
br.set_response(resp)
```