# Python mechanize checkboxes with dropdown submit

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, submit, mechanize, mechanize-python

I have an email client. I check the "checkboxes" of emails that I need do something (move,detele, egg) like this using python mechanize:

```
br.open(login_url)
br.open(url_1)
br.select_form(nr=0)
for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items)):
    if "4" in str(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i]):
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = False
    else:
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = True
reponseaa = br.submit()
print reponseaa

br.open(url_2)
br.select_form(nr=2)
for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items)):
    if "45198" and "4519" in str(br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i]):
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = True
    else:
        br.find_control(type="checkbox").items[i].selected = False
br.form['self'] = ["88"]
r1 = br.submit()
print r1
```

the problem is with the submit button, which is a dropdown menu, that looks like this:

```
<select name="self">
<option value="0">Select an action</option>
<option value="87">Move</option>
<option value="88">Delete</option>
<option value="89">Mark as Important</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Action!">
```

How I can select Delete and push the submit button? A code example would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [form from mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) :

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['self'] = ["88"]
r = br.submit()

print r.read()
```

Comment: I get this error:mechanize._form.ParseError: nested FORMs . I updated the code from the question to understand better what i do.

Comment: It's because you have one form inside another. Take a loot at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135964/submitting-nested-form-with-python-mechanize)

Comment: Its true. I have one : <form action="manager.php" method="GET"> and the other <form action="manager.php" method="post">. And the selection and the submit button are in the second one. BeutifulSoap didnt helped me. Any other ideas?