# Login to a website using Python and Mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to login to [portfolio123.com](https://www.portfolio123.com/login.jsp) using Mechanize. For some reason I am not getting the LoginPassword field.

Here is the code so far:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['LoginUsername'] = user_name 
br['LoginPassword'] = password # This line does not work yet.
```

The last line does not work. The control is not found. We can confirm this by running the following code:

```
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
for control in br.form.controls:
    print "type=%s, name=%s value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, br[control.name])
```

returns:

```
type=text, name=LoginUsername value=xxxxx
type=submit, name=Login value=Login
type=hidden, name=url value=index.jsp
```

But when I open the url in a browser the pasword field **is** there. So how do I get to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear why `Mechanize` doesn't see the `LoginPassword` field. I've tried multiple things: set a `User-Agent`, tried [prettifying the response with `BeautifulSoup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039584/771848) thinking about HTML-parsing problems, tried to modify the password input attributes on the fly etc.

As a workaround, [`robobrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) can handle the login form without any problems:

```
import robobrowser

url = "https://www.portfolio123.com/login.jsp"
browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser()
browser.open(url)

form = browser.get_form()
form['LoginUsername'] = 'Username'
form['LoginPassword'] = 'Password'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

Comment: Is there documentation on RoboBrowser? There are numerous tasks to do after logging in such as submitting other forms, executing JavaScript, downloading Excel sheets, etc. I am having a hard time with those.

Comment: How would I use RoboBrowser to click this buton: `<input class="btn" id="checkrec" name="checkrec" value="Get Recommendations" onclick="return submitReq()" type="submit">`? I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: I'm guessing that I need to either execute JavaScript (is this even possible from within RoboBrowser?) or duplicate the POST request that the JS sends.

Comment: I would prefer JS because that is less likely to break down the road but it doesn't seem like RoboBrowser can handle it. Therefore, I did the following: `response = browser.session.post("https://www.portfolio123.com/portf_rebalance.jsp", data=params)` which I'm guessing works through RoboBrowser to get at the requests library. The POST fields (in this particular case) are subject to change down the road and the library function is undocumented. Is there a JS way to do this?

Comment: @ChaimG from what I understand, you need a high-level approach without going down into how the requests to the server are formed, which parameters are sent etc. In this case, you should look into browser automation with `selenium`. Let me know if you need help with this approach.